# Can I run PlatformUi.getWorkbench() on a non-UI thread?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In the Eclipse API, will `PlatformUi.getWorkbench()` return null when run on a non-UI thread?

Comment: Have you tried calling `PlatformUi.getWorkbench()` from a background thread? What does it return?

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more specific. I'm going through some documentation for which it says `PlatformUI.getWorkbench()` will return `null` when run on a non-UI thread, however I've observed that it doesn't return `null` in the situation I'm using. This question is meant only to double check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem calling `PlatformUI.getWorkbench()` in a non-UI thread.

The call will return `null` if the workbench has not been started - so calling it from an ordinary Java program (rather than a plugin or Eclipse RCP) will not work.